# TypeScript handling type array or single value

Tags: typescript

I have an interface like this. And I am wondering what is the best case to handle this case:

```
interface Ia {
  a: string
}
let a: Ia | Ia[]
console.log(a[0].a)
```

TS throws me an error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'Ia'.
  Property '0' does not exist on type 'Ia'.
```

I know I could use `console.log((a as Ia[])[0].a)` but it is not readable at all. Does anyone have better suggestions?

Also, the real use case type has many properties inside not the single one `a: sting` as in the example.

Comment: If you know that `a` is an array, why then you say it is `Ia | Ia[]` ?

Comment: @MaciejSikora I am getting the data structure and it might be a list or a single value. I will have a check for that, but my question is about options to handle the actual type assignation and to check if there are any alternatives to `as`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have settled with:

```
interface Ia {
  a: string
}
let a: Ia | Ia[]
if (Array.isArray(a)){
  a = [a]
}
console.log(a[0].a)
```

Thank you @kaya3 and @maciej-sikora for suggestions

Answer (score 3):

If `a` is not an array, then `a[0]` does not make sense. You need to test whether it is an array, and treat it differently depending on the result of that test.

```js
interface Ia {
  a: string
}

let obj: Ia | Ia[] = { a: 'foo' };

function test(obj: Ia | Ia[]): void {
  console.log(Array.isArray(obj) ? obj[0].a : obj.a);
}
```

Or you can use this pattern, which takes advantage of control-flow type narrowing:

```js
function test2(obj: Ia | Ia[]): void {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) { obj = obj[0]; }
  // now obj: Ia is known not to be an array
  console.log(obj.a);
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=4&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJJ2QbwFDOXALmQGcwpQBzbAX22wBsIxkB7AIwCsj1kAfNOAG0AusgC8WfEQDkMFi2nJqAbjowAriARhgLEMkikAFOy4C+AkQEoiANxbAAJllzIEe4i0YA6eiwpGAIJQUHAAnt7AxMGhYSacVsgA-KycggAMwt4YRKbZVqq02BpaOnoGEKQATPFmPPzo1nYOzjh4wDDIQSHhkdE9caZWiZipHOJjGcLKSq7uIJ4+fgF5cAU0dEA)

Answer (score 0):

I propose create a getter for that, consider:

```
const getA = (x: Ia | Ia[]) => "a" in x ? x.a : x[0]?.a;

const a = getA({ a: 'I am a' });
const a2 = getA([{ a: 'I am also a ' }]);
```

Or uniform the type and use it always in the same way:

```
const uniform = (x: Ia | Ia[]): Ia => Array.isArray(a) ? a[0] : a;
```

Such function unify our type from the union to one member.